# Can the general statics theory equations be used to calculate force reactions for pinned-roller support system?

Tags: statics

Observe the figure below.

[image]

Left end is pinned while on the right there is a roller support. The system is statically determinate, i.e. the reaction forces can be found using simple 3 equlibrium equations of statics. Now, while using these equations, I would use the distances as it is before the system comes into equilibrium. However, after the system comes into equilibrium, the roller support has translated along the horizontal axis, because as it names implies, it can without any resistance. So the contact point between the beam and the roller support has changed and is different than what it was at the beginning. The distance of the roller support from the pinned support (or from the centroid of distributed force) is now different. So it means that the force reaction calculated at the roller support is not the same as we had already calculated using the initial distances.

In case I don't have access to FEA, how would I use analytical methods to properly predict the force reactions along vertical axis at pinned and roller support, after the system comes into equilibrium?

*EDIT:* So according to some comments and answers here, it was discovered that the rollers are fixed to the ground, so they couldn't move at all. What if I don't fix them to the ground (and make them kinda like a tyre), what would be the process of finding the reaction forces at each support now?

Comment: What analytical methods would you consider?

Comment: Which wouldn't involve the usage of initial distances but should take into account the actual distances after the equilibrium, if there exists any.

Comment: Thought you would have some knowledge of the "General Statics Theory Equations"...

Comment: I don't know what the "general statics theory equations" are, but the roller doesn't move.  Plus, Statics = doesn't move.

Comment: Even I don't know what @SolarMike is referring to, but I was just talking about the general theory that net forces = 0 N, and net moments = 0 N.m. If there exists something, I would welcome it.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq "But doesn't that assumption actually is totally opposite to the main assumption that the roller can actually translate along the horizontal axis" confused? or left a few out?

Comment: @RameezUlHaq, there is nothing in that drawing that would make the roller move.  The bar is pinned, it can't move.  Are you planning to analyze this according to the deflections in the steel?

Comment: @TigerGuy, so the rollers are fixed to the ground? I had been thinking that roller that we use in this scenerio are kinda like tyres, which are also free to translate along the horizontal.

Comment: People actually downvote without even understanding the question or what the OP is looking for. Sad.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq the bar is fixed, it can't move horizontally.  It's solid, it doesn't stretch.

Comment: @TigerGuy, I understand. I know that the bar cannot move horizontally. If it would, it won't be a static case. I am aware of that. But try to understand me as well, please. Replace the roller support with a tyre, and apply a transverse load on the rod somwhere. The tyre would move horizontally, right, until the whole system comes into equilibrium. How can I calculate the vertical reaction force on this tyre (after it comes into equilibrium) using analytics, and not using the non-linear FEA solver? I hope I have made my query clear now.

Comment: Unless the statics way altogether assumes that the bar/beam/rod itself is a rigid body and cannot deform at all.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq, a tire cannot roll because the bar cannot move.  A force against a pin does nothing.  The bar will always be stationary, there is no equilibrium position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, you are overthinking and making a simple matter confusing.

As the beam is merely in contact with the roller, in order to move the beam horizontally and cause the roller to displace, two conditions must coexist - a horizontal load and the system has no horizontal restraint, the system shown does not meet both of the necessary conditions. A reminder - we are talking about rigid body statics and general beam theory. The former does not deal with internal stresses, and the latter was developed for beams with small deformation only.

Comment: Yes, you cleared it out for me now. So basically, whether I use a roller support fixed to ground or instead a tyre (which can move horizontally without any restrain), the reaction forces coming from the statics theory will still remain the same since we are assuming that the rod itself is a RIGID BODY, so it cannot deform. So these reaction forces gotten from statics are somewhat only applicable for small strains. Can you enlighten me with any method (without the use of non-linear FEA solvers) that we can use by hand to find the reaction forces if the body was not rigid?

Comment: If the roller is a deformable body, say rubber, then it can deform to an extent that renders the inapplicability of the general beam theory.  But for a first-hand approximation, I think you can still use the equations to calculate the deflection and rotation of the connection, then figure out the location of the shifted beam-roller contact point and the normal force to its tangent, which will provide the necessary horizontal force to cause the motion.

Answer (score 1):

The usual assumption in these kinds of problems is that the **position** of the roller support is fixed (by some kind of thing not drawn in the cartoon).  i.e. the roller does not impart any horizontal force to the beam, but it does not itself translate.

Comment: Did you mean that we are actually fixing the roller at the bottom end, and just placing beam ontop of it? so that the contact point between the beam and roller support will change over time, but it would be the beam contact point which could translate along the horizontal axis but not the roller.

Comment: So what I was thinking is that, or atleast what has been taught to us, the roller supports are free to translate along the horizontal, and the beam contact point lying ontop of it are also free to translate along the horizontal. That is what triggered this question that I have asked.

Comment: And assume, if I have a tyre like support instead of the roller (which can now actually translate along the horizontal), what should I do to analytically calculate the vertical reaction forces at both supports now?

Answer (score 0):

When we use statically determinate equations we assume we have small angles, so that we can superpose stressed and strains. e.g. we set the sum of $\sigma F_x=0$ even if forces F1, F2, F3 are applied on different points along the length of the beam

With small angle realm deflections and rotations are very small, even more so any changes in the length of the beam causing the roller to move.

A roller if it is loaded by a beam that is not going to move or expand won't roll.

** EDIT**

After a comment about small angles, I add this.

as per Euler beam theory we assume cross-sections remain planar after deformation and that is possible by assuming small angles: sinθ=θ

Comment: I don't think that we have an assumption that the rotations are small, for statically determinate structures. Consider a cantilever beam fixed at one end and force applied on the other. Doesn't matter if the rotations are small or large, still the reactions will be same. Ofcourse, Large Strain method should be used to calculate the deflections instead of Small Strain method if the rotations are large, but for reaction forces, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But for reaction forces, should it matter? I just gave you an example in my previous comment. Reaction forces are independent of the beam theory, rather it be Euler or Timoshenko or something else, as far as I know.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq If the distance of the roller is not changing after equilibrium, its reaction is not changing either.

Comment: yes, after we set sum of forces and reactions =0 nothing changes. otherwise we have acceleration and dynamics.

Comment: So yes, I think the statics way gives us reaction forces assuming that the strains are small.  And that is why we SHOULD NOT be dependent on statics (i.e. the analytical approach) to calculate the reaction forces if the strains are anticipated to be large. I wonder if there exists any method to determine the reaction forces if the strains are large (without using any non-linear FEA solver).